# Find which MDI child just got focus Win32 API

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

I have a program that has a MDI host and I would like to be able to get which of it children just got focus, bassiclly I would like to make a window focus changed event for this application.

The application is a 3rd party and I don't have the source,  I have the window handle to the main program and the MDI host part.

I know I'll have to use Win32 API just not sure which ones.

I am writing my application in C#

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this question during the day. Everyone who knows the answer to this is asleep. Worn out by the kids. Or just plain gravity.

Comment: Well it's daylight in Aus where I live :P, but we'll see. I'm sure someone will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is intercepting [WM_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646283(VS.85).aspx) and [WM_KILLFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646282(VS.85).aspx) messages

The real problem is how are you going to do this. I guess the easiet way is to install a [hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx) which is a subroutine to monitor the message traffic in the system and process certain types of messages before they reach the target window procedure. You're doing it by using [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) winapi function with WH_CALLWNDPROC or WH_CALLWNDPROCRET types of hooks. There some are examples posted on codeproject; also there is one on msdn: [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;318804)

What is not really clear in your post is where your code running: in the same process with the MDI windows or is it a separate application\service? In case it is you would also need to inject your code into the remote process. Check this link for details on how you can do it: [Three Ways to Inject Your Code into Another Process](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx)

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Since he has the handles, he can inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow` and call `AssignHandle(IntPtr)`.  He can then listen to the messages for the particular window using `WndProc`.

Comment: agree, NativeWindow should also work; I would still stay with a hook as it IMHO less hassle to assign and it works for the whole application; besides it's not known if his window handles belong to the same process where his code is running

Comment: My plug in runs in it's own appdomian within the main application,  would this cause a problem?

Comment: separate appdomain shouldn't be a problem. Also, pls, disregard "injection" portion of my post; I believe you don't need it for your task

Comment: Thanks,  I have looked into it a bit, but haven't gotten very far.  I'm not very strong in the Win32 API section.

Comment: you might want to get yourself one of these: http://www.amazon.com/Windows-via-Pro-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735624240 which is a great book for somebody who wants to know more about winapi; I have a couple of previous editions of this book. Also this one http://www.amazon.com/Windows%C2%AE-Internals-Including-Windows-PRO-Developer/dp/0735625301/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1263914641&sr=1-1 is a great book about how the core components of the Windows operating system work